# Wordpress site on nginx localhost, can't load css/js

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

I'm trying to setup a development environment on my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04, and I've somehow mucked up the configuration of my local nginx server.

I have a LEMP stack, set up via this [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lemp-on-ubuntu-16-04). I finally got the index.php to load, after some difficulty, but none of the assets (css, js, etc.) are loading. These are the requests that throw errors in the console after they fail to load:

```
GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css?ver=4.7.2 
GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4 
GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/genericons/genericons.css?ver=3.4.1 
GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1 
GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js?ver=20160816 
GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7.2 
GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/js/functions.js?ver=20160816 
GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.7.2
GET http://localhost/wordpress/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.7.2 404 (Not Found)
```

I think I know why they don't load; they're all looking for files that don't exist because that have that `?ver=x.x.x` appended to the end of the filename. But I thought this was supposed to be dealt with by the location blocks inside the server block in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
location = /robots.txt { log_not_found off; access_log off; allow all; }
location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|png)$ {
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

location / {
    # proxy_pass http://localhost:4040;
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Clearly it's still missing the file references somehow, but I'm not sure how what's wrong with my syntax.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a mismatch between your `root` and [the WordPress Site URL](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)?

Comment: I don't think so. It's finding index.php and loading it, just not any of the references it contains.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the `?ver=x.x...` on the end. (*Thats a cache reloading mechanism*). Also, when I run WordPress on Nginx I tend to use this try_files for my `/` location: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;`. Might be worth a shot?

Comment: Yes. You already said that, hence my comment. What is the value of root, site URL, and the physical location of one of the files it cannot find?

Comment: @Darren thanks, I tried that syntax too, but no dice.
@RichardSmith, the root value is `/var/www/html` and the location for the stylesheet is `/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen/style.css` ... hmm, so is it looking for `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/.../style.css`, is that the problem?

Comment: Ahhh, I found the trouble.... there was an old broken symlink in the namespace `/var/www/html/wordpress` from an old install. It was preventing me from copying my new directory `wordpress` in that location, which is why all the files got dumped directly into the parent directory, `html`. Thanks @RichardSmith!